# jQueryUI modal causing height to increase

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Why does the height of the page increase when the modal is active, causing it to show low on the page (in firefox at least)? Thank you ...

Comment: Try setting the dialog's position to absolute

Comment: That worked.  Not using the jqueryui.css has messed me up a couple times.  Thanks for the answer.  Wanna make an answer so I can close this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default relative positioning adds to the height.
Setting the dialog's position to absolute will position it correctly.